# How to filter on Window value in Clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I'm trying to use a WHERE clause to filter when the student count > 1 so that the following table:

```
    | University  | Student  |Program   |student_count|
    | ----------- | ---------| -------- | ----------- | 
    | University A| Student 1| Program A|2            |
    | University A| Student 2| Program A|2            |
    | University A| Student 3| Program B|1            |
    | University B| Student 4| Program A|1            |
    | University B| Student 5| Program B|1            |
```

returns:

```
    | University  | Student  |Program   |student_count|
    | ----------- | ---------| -------- | ----------- | 
    | University A| Student 1| Program A|2            |
    | University A| Student 2| Program A|2            |
```

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT 
    University,
    Program, 
    Student,
    count(*) over (partition by University, Program) as student_count
FROM 
    table;
WHERE 
student_count > 1
```

On the original table:

```
| University  | Student   | Program   |
| ----------- | --------- | --------- |
| University A| Student 1 | Program A |
| University A| Student 2 | Program A |
| University A| Student 3 | Program B |
| University B| Student 4 | Program A |
| University B| Student 5 | Program B |
```

However this is not a valid way, is there a way to achieve this in clickhouse without inserting another table?

Comment: Take a look at using GROUP BY and HAVING to achieve your desired results https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/group-by

Comment: @craig I originally tried approaching this with a GROUP BY, however I understand it would mean that I would have to include all fields in the aggregate for the GROUP BY which I would not want to do. I would like to include all other fields in the table, just not under a GROUP BY

Comment: Seems you are not really understanding the use of GROUP BY.  When you use GROUP BY, you specify either fields that you want to aggregate (in your example, the COUNT), or fields that are not aggregated (in your example, University, Program, Student - and those are the fields that are nominated in the GROUP BY clause)

Comment: In this example I do not want the students in the GROUP BY, which is why I created the Window. I expanded on this in the post

Comment: Hi - my misunderstanding, since your initial posting of the question hadn't shown the sample data in the original table.  ValNik's answer gives you the best approach, then, by using your preliminary query as a sub-query, to then allow you to filter down to the final required results

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want some like this

```
select *
from (
   SELECT 
      University,
      Program, 
      Student,
      count(*) over (partition by University, Program) as student_count
   FROM table
   ) filter
WHERE 
student_count > 1
```